# Как задать условие, которое не позволит пользователю начинать ввод данных с "0"?

Tags: swift

Начал изучать свифт. Хочу понять, как прописать условие, которое не позволит пользователю писать юзернейм, начинающийся с нуля (или любого другого символа на моё усмотрение).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте метод [hasPrefix](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1540100-hasprefix) у String:

```
func hasPrefix(_ prefix: String) -> Bool
```

---

Или регулярные выражения:

```
username.range(of: #"^0"#, options: .regularExpression) == nil
```